# Error: No hemos podido encontrar el archivo. ¿Es posible se haya movido, cambiado de nombre o eliminado?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tengo un proyecto en asp.net C#, quiero crear un documento Word con los datos que ingreso el usuario en el Web Form.

Me da un error de ruta:
Lo sentimos, no hemos podido encontrar el archivo. ¿Es posible se haya movido, cambiado de nombre o eliminado?

El error me marca en la línea:

`Word.Document ObjDoc = ObjWord.Documents.Open(parametro,ObjMiss);`

Lo he modificado varias veces y me sigue dando el mismo error.

Este es mi código:

```
   protected void btnguardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        object ObjMiss = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        Word.Application ObjWord = new Word.Application();
        string ruta = Server.MapPath (@"\solicitud.docx");
        object parametro = ruta;
        object fecha1 = "fecha";
        object solicitud1 = "solicitud";
        object nomsol1 = "nomsol";
        object extsol1 = "correosol";
         object justif1 = "justif";
        object observ1 = "observ";

        Word.Document ObjDoc = ObjWord.Documents.Open(parametro,ObjMiss);
        Word.Range fech = ObjDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref fecha1).Range;
        fech.Text = txtfechatenci.Text;
        Word.Range solicitu = ObjDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref solicitud1).Range;
        solicitu.Text = txtfolio2.Text;
        Word.Range nomsolicitan = ObjDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref nomsol1).Range;
        nomsolicitan.Text = txtnomseg.Text;
        Word.Range corrsolicit = ObjDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref correosol1).Range;
        corrsolicit.Text = txtcorrseg.Text;
         Word.Range justific = ObjDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref justif1).Range;
        justific.Text = txtjustifseg.Text;
        Word.Range observac = ObjDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref observ1).Range;
        observac.Text = txtobserseg.Text;

        object rango1 = fech;
        object rango2 = solicitu;
        object rango3 = nomsolicitan;
        object rango6 = corrsolicit;
        object rango15 = justific;
        object rango16 = observac;

        ObjDoc.Bookmarks.Add("fecha", ref rango1);
        ObjDoc.Bookmarks.Add("solicitud", ref rango2);
        ObjDoc.Bookmarks.Add("nomsol", ref rango3);
        ObjDoc.Bookmarks.Add("correosol", ref rango4);
        ObjDoc.Bookmarks.Add("justif", ref rango15);
        ObjDoc.Bookmarks.Add("observ", ref rango16);

        ObjWord.Visible = true;

    }
```

Comment: `string ruta = Server.MapPath (@"\solicitud.docx");` ¿seguro que está tomando la **ruta correcta** y el archivo solicitud.docx **existe** en dicha ruta?

Comment: @A.Cedano Si existe, está en mi escritorio así se llama el documento, también he intentado con:  string ruta = Server.MapPath ("solicitud.docx"); y aún así no me da

Comment: @KlonDTS podrías poner un _punto de interrupción_ e indicarnos que valor tiene tu variable `ruta`.

Comment: @Davlio me marca null.

Comment: ¿Estás usando bien `Server.MapPath (@" ...` ?http://stackoverflow.com/a/275791/5587982 Yo pondría, para probar, una cadena con la ruta completa en lugar de obtenerla con Server.MapPath... `string ruta="la/ruta/completa/folders/incluidos..."` cuestión de ir depurando.

Comment: He votado la pregunta para cierre por el motivo siguiente: _Parece ser un problema que no se puede reproducir o un **error tipográfico**._

Comment: @KlonDTS prueba: `@.\solicitud.docx` esto es para localizar tu archivo word _en la misma ubicación en donde se encuentra tu aplicación_. Revisa también si tienes procesos abiertos de Word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¿Has intentado con `string ruta = Server.MapPath (@"~/solicitud.docx");` (con el `~` al principio)? Esto te da no la carpeta "escritorio" de tu usuario, sino la ruta base de tu aplicación web, por ejemplo, `C:\Users\TU_USUARIO\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Proyecto Web\Proyecto Web`, así que puedes probar a poner el documento ahí e intentar hacer las operaciones ahí. Puedes consultar [aquí (en inglés)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275781/server-mappath-server-mappath-server-mappath-server-mappath) cómo funciona `Server.MapPath`.

Ahora bien, puedes crear dentro del proyecto una carpeta que sea específica para ese (esos) archivo(s) y apuntar ahí con `Server.MapPath (@"~/docs/solicitud.docx");`.